# issue while submitting new version of existing application - application loader stuck on authentication with app store

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am trying to submit the new version of my existing application but it keeps on loading in the application loader. It even doesn't giving me any error.

I do have 3 years of experience of submitting application to app store, so I don't think I am missing anything.

I have downloaded new application loader that is 2.9 and tried from that to but the same result.

I also tried to submitting different application but still the same result.

Is there any issue or change after iOS 7 release for submitting the application?
Please let me know if anyone has faced similer problem.

Thank you

Comment: why can't you try submitting app from your xcode directly?

Comment: @Nazik, Thanks for your comment, I also tried from the xcode, Same result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the provisioning profile, I don't know why but I need to create new provisioning profile and than only it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to. I had changed passwords recently and so you need to re-authenticate with via application loader. Passwords get cached locally, so have you tried "sign in as" from the menu and re-authenticated ? This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... The problem was with the provisioning profile, I need to generate new in order to submit it.